# Need a tensioning rod to push something tight (opposite of a turnbuckle)

Tags: tools, terminology

I need rod that can push two blocks of wood apart. The space is about 16" wide.

So, basically it is the opposite of a turnbuckle, kind of like a tensioned shower rod.

Is there any kind of standard mechanical device to do this, and if so, what is it called?

Comment: https://kitsplit.com/rent/2x4-wood-wall-spreaders-threaded-end-cap-brooklyn-ny-11211  Is that what you're looking for?  I Googled "threaded spreader."

Comment: Permanent or temporary? If temporary I'd use a hydraulic car jack and some wood pieces of the right length.

Comment: Or any other type car jack.

Answer (score 3):

Where we need to separate like you are mentioning we use what the millwright call jacking bolts.
These are heavy 1/2” or better. In some cases they use a threaded rod  (short distances up to about a foot).
If longer than a foot they use the same or larger thread stock and weld it onto a plate or tube steel the tube steel just a 2x2 can span 6’ - 8’.

The millwrights usually use national course threads but I have seen them use acme square on 2” thread stock for a heavier load (several tons) needed to be lifted but maintain adjustability.

I don’t know if there are other ways like a reversed turnbuckle but the millwrights use standard stock and the nuts and washers on the inside push the parts away from each other and they call them jacking bolts.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this? It is the Westinghouse Saf-T-Brace model 01100, and supports 68 kg. on 16" center-spaced joists, or 22.6 kg. on 24" center-spaced joists.

It is meant to span ceiling joists to hang a ceiling fan. It expands from about 14" to 24" when you rotate the bar. The tangs are driven into the joists as you expand it, and the black triangular pieces' flat edges sit against the ceiling drywall and keeps the ends from rotating uselessly so that the screw operates correctly. The electrical box is hung afterwards, but does not have to be used if you just want a spreader bar.

I used it vertically to give some extra support for an under-counter sink.

I was originally going to use a 3/4" threaded rod and use some nuts, washers, and center-drilled wood blocks at the ends, but I was only able to buy threaded rods in 12' lengths, so the costs were similar.

[image: Westinghouse Saf-T-Brace]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, use the turnbuckle backwards.

Run the screws all the way in, place the turnbuckle, unscrew it to lengthen and exert some force.

Of course, this will not work if cable is attached, and you may need some sort of swivel to attach the loops to the material being pushed.